# How to use the maybe monoid and combine values with a custom operation, easily?

Tags: haskell, monoids

What I'm trying to do is trivial to define by hand, basically

```
maybeCombine :: (a->a->a) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
maybeCombine _ Nothing Nothing = Nothing
maybeCombine _ (Just a) Nothing = Just a
maybeCombine _ Nothing (Just a) = Just a
maybeCombine f (Just a) (Just a') = Just $ f a a'
```

It's not a big deal to [define this locally when needed](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/timed-media/blob/master/Media/Timed/MiscUtil/Data.hs), but still cumbersone and being so basic and general it seems there should be a standard implementation, yet I can't seem to find one.

Perhaps I'm just overlooking something. What I want seems quite unrelated on the behaviour of the maybe monad, so I reckon I won't find anything in the Monad/Arrow drawers; but it sure resembles the `Monoid` instance

> Prelude Data.Monoid> Just "a" <> Nothing
>   
> Just "a"
>    
> Prelude Data.Monoid> Just "a" <> Just "b"
>     
>   Just "ab"
>     
> ...

...which however requires `a` to be a monoid itself, i.e. that it basically has the `a->a->a` "built in". The `MonadPlus` instance also behaves much like I want, but it simply throws away one of the values rather than allowing me to supply a combination function

> Prelude Data.Monoid Control.Monad> Just 4 `mplus` Nothing
>   Just 4
>   Prelude Data.Monoid Control.Monad> Nothing `mplus` Just 4
>   Just 4
>   Prelude Data.Monoid Control.Monad> Just 4 `mplus` Just 5
>   Just 4

**What would be the canonical solution?** Local pattern matching? Something with combinators from e.g. `Data.Maybe`? Defining a custom monoid to do the combining?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right on the money when you notice that the `f` is like a `Monoid` operation on the underlying `a` type. More specifically what's going on here is you're lifting a `Semigroup` into a `Monoid` by adjoining a zero (`mempty`), `Nothing`.

This is exactly what you see in the Haddocks for the `Maybe` `Monoid` actually.

> Lift a semigroup into Maybe forming a Monoid according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid: "Any semigroup S may be turned into a monoid simply by adjoining an element e not in S and defining e*e = e and e*s = s = s*e for all s ∈ S." Since there is no "Semigroup" typeclass providing just mappend, we use Monoid instead.

Or, if you like the [`semigroups`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups) package, then there's [`Option`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.11/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Option) which has exactly this behavior, suitably generalized to use an underlying `Semigroup` instead.

---

So that suggests the clearest way is to define either a `Monoid` or `Semigroup` instance on the underlying type `a`. It's a clean way to associate some combiner `f` with that type.

What if you don't control that type, don't want orphan instances, and think a `newtype` wrapper is ugly? Normally you'd be out of luck, but this is one place where using the total black magic, effectively GHC-only [`reflection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package comes in handy. Thorough explanations exist [in the paper itself](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/prepose/prepose.pdf) but [Ausin Seipp's FP Complete Tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection) includes some example code to allow you to "inject" arbitrary semigroup products into types without (as much) type definition noise... at the cost of a lot scarier signatures.

That's probably significantly more overhead than its worth, however.

Comment: I'm not out of luck, in the problem I'm working on right now I can in fact use the `Max` semigroup and get a really nice solution!

Comment: Awesome! I often end up defining `Option (Max a)` as adjoining a "negative infinity" on to a type, so absolutely. I think that's a really elegant `Monoid`.

Answer (score 12):

You can always use

```
f <$> m <*> n <|> m <|> n
```

But this, sadly, doesn't have a canonical implementation anywhere.

You can use `reflection` to get that `(a -> a -> a)` "baked in" as the `Semigroup` for use with `Option`, which is provided by `semigroups` as an improved version of `Maybe` that has the 'right' instance for `Monoid` in terms of `Semigroup`. This is rather too heavy handed for this problem though. =)

Perhaps this should just be added as a combinator to `Data.Maybe`.

Comment: Right, I forgot about `Alternative`! This is quite good, but I think I prefer the elegance of `Semigroup`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.Monoid
maybeCombine :: (a->a->a) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
maybeCombine f mx my = let combine = mx >>= (\x -> my >>= (\y -> Just (f x y)))
                       in getFirst $ First combine `mappend` First mx `mappend` First` my
```

in GHCi, this gives me

```
*Main> maybeCombine (+) Nothing Nothing
Nothing
*Main> maybeCombine (+) (Just 3) Nothing
Just 3
*Main> maybeCombine (+) (Just 3) (Just 5)
Just 8
```

Also works with `getLast` if you put `Last combine` at the end of the `mappend` sequence

Comment: I concede this isn't as generic a solution as J. Abrahamson's ;)

Comment: +1 for answering a previously unadressed (and perhaps the most straightforward) aspect of this question... but honestly, this implementation is neither shorter nor more readable than my original stupid pattern-matching one. I also can't quite see how it might be better adaptable to variations in the requirement.

Comment: You can golf this method down to something almost as pithy as Ed's solution—`getFirst . mconcat . map First $ [liftA2 f mx my, mx, my]`, or even replace `getFirst . mconcat . map First` with `msum` though it's arguably less clear without the `First`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It would be prettier with `do` notation and I know it could be made shorter with lifting (thanks, J ;) but I just wanted to make the basic technique clear.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I also don't see any justice in " I also can't quite see how it might be better adaptable to variations in the requirement."  Your current requirements can be expressed purely in terms of the Maybe monad; if you change the requirements but they are still expressible via Maybe, this technique can be extended to fit.  If not, not.  You want a solution that would generically fit *any* arbitrary variation in requirements?  Well, OK, it's called "Haskell"

Comment: No no... I just meant, I don't see any application where your suggestion would actually be better than either of the previous ones. It's still a useful answer and all, and I think the `First` monoid is an interesting and unexpected consideration that might come in handy in other problems. – Only, I then couldn't think of any such problem that would look anything like the one in this question, hence my probably confusing remark.

Comment: Note about [First](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First): "This type will be marked **deprecated** in GHC 8.8, and removed in GHC 8.10. Users are advised to use the variant from Data.Semigroup and wrap it in Maybe."